# Why do I get snapshot error and setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build?

Tags: flutter

When no internet available I get

```
No internet :( Reason: bla bla
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building FutureBuilder<bool>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<bool>#bf2f3):
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

and it renders `snapshot.hasError` part on screen

the code

```
Future<void> main() async {
  setupServiceLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Internet(),
    );
  }
}

class Internet extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: checkConnection(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          var result = snapshot.data;
          if (result = true) {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AllMessages(),
            );
          }
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Text('No internet :('),
                SizedBox(height: 30),
                RaisedButton(
                  child: Text('Try again'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Internet());
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          );
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print(snapshot.error);
          print('snapshot has error');
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: Text('Error. \nSomething went wrong :('),
            ),
          );
        } else {
          return Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

Future<bool> checkConnection() async {
  bool result = await DataConnectionChecker().hasConnection;
  if (result == true) {
    print('YAY! Free cute dog pics!');
  } else {
    print('No internet :( Reason:');
    print(DataConnectionChecker().lastTryResults);
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are navigating to a different MaterialPage and then trying to return a widget. What do you wish to do when hasData is true?

Comment: Wnen hasData is true it should check the data: if it's true (i.e. internet is available) then it should render AllMessages() screen, othervise it should render a part with `No internet :('` text and button to try again.

Comment: But you are navigating away from the page with the following code: Navigator.pushReplacement.  Can you display allmessages() on same page?

Comment: you were partly right because there was another error - I had `if (result = true) {` which makes running a wrong part of the code

Comment: That was the part I was trying to bring to your notice. When result = true, you were navigating away from the page.